# tabbar containg navigation and view based application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i ve got a three tab bar where the first tab bar has got a table view ..works fine and the second tab bar has got a UIviewController which contains three buttons..if i am to click any one of the button it got to navigate to another view.In my button s (IBACtion)..I ve coded  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:newEnterNameController1 animated:YES]; the button s IBaction is not working .
my guess was in app delegate class...i should add navigation controller as my subview but doing that would make my tab bar not visible....is there any way to add navigation controller as my window sub view....or any other method to show my uiview,tableview and tab bar in iphone app

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to add your `NavigationController` to the `tabBarController`'s array of controllers before adding the `tabBarController` to the main window.
Example:

```
NSArray *controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:yourNavController, someOtherController, nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```